# Software for multi-objective optimization

Tags: nonlinear-programming, software, multi-objective-optimization, chance-constraints

I am looking to solve a multi-objective chance-constrained blending problem. Are there any suggestions about the software to use to try and solve a problem like this?

Comment: Would you see [the multi-objective optimization laboratory](http://www.eng.usf.edu/~hcharkhgard/) which was founded at University of South Florida?

Comment: I have edited your title to include multi-objective optimization, and also to avoid the word "best", since your question doesn't ask for the "best", and since such a question would be subjective (and therefore not a great fit for OR.SE) anyway. Feel free to re-edit the title if I've introduced any errors.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Thank you for the edit, and thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 7):

You may be interested in the following paper because it uses chance-constrained programming and bi-objective optimization together in a transportation application:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10288-019-00429-7

I would suggest to do the followings for your problem:

1- If you have bi-linear terms in your formulation then try to linearize them using for example "Piecewise mccormick relaxation".

2-   Generate a reasonable (and tractable) number of scenarios to generate/expand the chance constraint(s) in your formulation.

3-1- If your problem has two 2 objective functions then you can pass your formulation to 
the "triangle splitting method" (which is an exact method) embedded in the following julia package to solve it:

https://github.com/alvsierra286/OOESAlgorithm.jl

(*) https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/itor.12692

3-2- If your problem has more than two objective functions then you can pass your formulation to the following julia generic heuristic package to solve it:

https://github.com/aritrasep/FPBH.jl

(*) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305054819301947